# 'MobileApp.Droid.Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'design_navigation_padding_top_default'

Tags: android, nuget, google-play-services, xamarin.forms

I was trying to update xamarin.forms dll and Google + Android nuget packages

So after updating packages, starting getting messgaes

```
Error   282 'MobileApp.Droid.Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'design_navigation_padding_top_default'  D:\projects\Code\MobileApp\MobileApp.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs   525 151 MobileApp.Droid
```

I udpated Xamarin.Forms Google GCM, Location, Fitness and Map nuget packages.